# How to create a new data frame by matching elements in a list with another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

Match elements present in list on dataframe and create a new result dataframe

I have a list like below:

```
newlist = ["email","common name"]
```

The data frame is like below:

| DisplayName | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| firstname | givenName |
| lastname | sn |
| email | mail |

How can I search for list values present in dataframe and then create a new dataframe like below:

`df[value] = email + '='+ mail`

Example is below:

```
| DisplayName    | Column B | Value              |
|--------------- |--------- | -------------------|
|firstname       | givenName| firstname=givenName|
|lastname        | sn       | lastname=sn        |
|email           | mail     | email=mail         |
```

Comment: Python doesn't have dataframes. That data structure comes from pandas. Please always include the pandas tag when asking pandas questions, as described in the Python tag wiki: "When using a Python variant (e.g. Jython, PyPy) or library (e.g. Pandas, NumPy), please include it in the tags".

Comment: Can you provide an example as well of the output you are looking for?

Comment: @MAK7 I will include the example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use `DataFrame.isin`:

```py
newlist = ["email","lastname"]

new_df = df[df['DisplayName'].isin(newlist)].copy()
new_df['Value'] = new_df['DisplayName'] + '=' + new_df['Column B']

print(new_df)
```

Prints:

```
  DisplayName Column B        Value
1    lastname       sn  lastname=sn
2       email     mail   email=mail
```

Answer (score -1):

Import the required libraries: Usually, you would need to import libraries such as Pandas to work with data frames. Make sure you have the necessary libraries installed.

import pandas as pd

Create a list of elements: Define a list containing the elements you want to match with the data frame.

elements_list = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3']

Create the data frame: Create a data frame using the pd.DataFrame() function or load an existing data frame from a file.

## Create a sample data frame

data = {'Column1': ['element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'element4', 'element5'], 'Column2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure to read questions carefully before posting your answers. Your post does not address the question right now at all. You are just showing how to create a dataframe from a list that you created. The question shows the specific output that needs to be produced.